# SMTP server that only writes emails as eml files

Tags: email, smtp

We have a piece of 3rd party software that all our outgoing emails are sent from, it is configured to send to an SMTP server. We need to intercept these mails so we can alter them with dynamic signatures, change the from address and multiple other things based on a custom set of rules.

We cannot send the emails via Exchange due to an incompatibility with the 3rd party software.

Our idea is to have a intermediary SMTP server that receives the mail from the 3rd party software and writes out the emails to disk as EML files. I would than have a .NET program listening for these files to be written to disk which would make the necessary alterations and send them to the actual SMTP server.

There are a few apps I've seen around that look to be mainly used for testing email code before you want to send out real emails but I don't think these would scale to our volumes.

Does anyone know of a piece of software that can do the receiving and writing to disk portion, and at scale?

We will work on getting the 3rd party software to fix its issues, but unfortunately that doesn't seem like it's going to possible within out timelines.

Comment: A couple of things: 1. When you say "There are a few apps I've seen around that look to be mainly used for testing email code before you want to send out real emails but I don't think these would scale to our volumes" you're really just guessing. Why don't you try one and see if it in fact does scale to your volume? 2. When you say "Does anyone know of a piece of software that can do the receiving and writing to disk portion, and at scale?" you're making a statement that can't be quantified. Scale to you may be vastly different to me. Can you clarify with some actual numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using [procmail](http://www.procmail.org/)?

With procmail you should be able to dump your mail to a file or redirect it to be processed by a script or program.

[Here is an example of using it to dump to a php script.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4964600/postfix-send-email-to-php)

Comment: This looks like it would work, but we actually ended up going with http://www.hmailserver.com/ which has a 'scripts' setting that lets you hook onto events and stop the email being sent on.

Answer (score 0):

Simple. Was looking for the same and it dawned on me. Use another smtp server to drop the eml files into its queue by telling it to send to a non existing smtp relay. Have a bat process or what have you pick them up deleting the failed delivery log and then process them and place into the working smtp servers pickup folder. Done.:)

Answer (score 0):

try this.. very simple and nice..
http://emailrelay.sourceforge.net/

we use it this tool in our secure domain. 
in domain ABC this tool listen and recive emails and write them to disk.
we then move these files to Domain XYZ

in domain XYZ
we have same tool setup to scan local dir and send email every 1 min. we simply move email files from ABC domain to XYZ domain in the dir where this tool is scanning.